# Why am I getting "Job for httpd.service failed...," and how do I go about fixing it?

Tags: arch-linux, apache-httpd

I am running Arch Linux 3.12.25-1-ARCH and httpd.service is now giving me problems.

```
$ sudo systemctl enable httpd.service
$ sudo systemctl start httpd.service
Job for httpd.service failed. See 'systemctl status httpd.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

`systemctl status httpd.service` returns...

```
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled)
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since...
 Process: 341 ExecStart=/usr/bin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)`
```

`journalctl -xn` returns many entries, but there are none that are of an erroneous nature.

I had initially followed [this guide](http://sudopacman.wordpress.com/2014/03/15/upgrading-to-apache-2-4/)

That did the trick, but after a reboot, it isn't working any longer. I went back through and verified that the `httpd.conf` file was the same, and I also tried to do reinstall with `pacman -S apache php php-apache`

Comment: What happens when you start apache directly with `/usr/bin/apachectl start`?

Comment: When I attempt to start Apache directly, I receive this error message:

AH00526: Syntax error on line 48 of /etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf: Invalid command 'SSLCipherSuite', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Line 48 of the aforementioned is `SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that I didn't have OpenSSL properly installed. I installed using `sudo pacman -S openssl`. Then, I tried restarting Apache again, and got an additional error regarding a missing certificate. I used [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-on-arch-linux) to create a self-signed certificate and then was able to properly enable and start `httpd.service`.